# Using OAuth 2.0 within a Google Doc container bound script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-docs, google-drive-api

I know the means of using the OAuth 1.0 flow for making calls to Google APIs (including calls to the Google Drive API).

However, Drive is now using OAuth 2.0, and I want to adjust my Google Doc container based script such that it can access the Google Drive API (and likely others) using the new authentication flow.

I would like to know what Redirect URIs and Javascript origins are for my Google Docs container based script.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to apply oauth 2.0 to installed application. Here is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) about it. This documentation exactly answers your question about `redirect URI`. For `Javascript origin`, if your application is web application and if it is using Javascript, you should set this to be the url of your application. If not, just set it as `http://localhost`. It doesn't matter.